# If S has a subset A which is infinite, then S must also be infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

From IN Herstein's Topics in Algebra, there is a question (Exercise 1.2.13), a set S is called infinite if there exists a proper subset, A, of that set such that there is a one-to-one correspondence between S and A.

Question: We need to prove that if S has a subset A, which is infinite, then S is infinite.

I am very confused as to how we can prove this but I have tried my hand at proof by contradiction. Note how the question itself does not say if A is a proper subset or not. Also the concept of cardinality has not been introduced yet.

Contradiction: Let S not be infinite. This means there does not exist a proper subset of S, with a one-to-one correspondence between it and S. However we know that A is an infinite set. Which means A has a proper subset, say B, between which there is a one-to-one correspondence.

How do I go further than this?

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to: 'If $S$ is finite, then all of its subset are finite'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed directly. Here's a picture hint of how you could construct a one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and a proper subset.

[image]

Comment: Is f the correspondence between A and its proper subset which we used to prove that it is infinite?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, that's right.

Comment: But which proper subset of S do I use? I am still confused. I understand that if we take s $\in$ S, such that it is not in A, we map it to itself. What happens to the other elements? How do we map those? And how do we know this new subset we get will be a proper subset of S?

Comment: The proper subset I am proposing is $S \setminus (A \setminus f(A))$, or equivalently, $(S \setminus A) \cup f(A)$ (they are both the same sets, and the previous union is disjoint).

Comment: The defining property of $f$ says that $A$ is in correspondence with a **proper** subset of $A$ (which is $f(A)$). So $A \setminus f(A)$ is non-empty.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks so much! A great drawing!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is infinite, there is a proper subset $B \subsetneq A$ and a bijection $f : B \to A$. How does this help to construct a proper subset $C \subsetneq S$ and a bijection $g : C \to S$?

SPOILER:

Consider the set $C = (S \setminus A) \cup B$. It is a proper subset, as $B$ is a proper subset of $A$. A bijection is now given by $$g(z) = \begin{cases} f(z) & z \in B \\ z & z \in (S\setminus A) \end{cases}.$$